# How to lock BottomAppBar position?

Tags: android

My BottomAppBar have no fixed position. When I open the keyboard my app bar gets out upward (see the image below).

How can I fix it?

This is my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".session.AddSessionActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Container with other widgets -->

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar_new_session"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
        app:hideOnScroll="true"

        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: Demo gif]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your manifest. You need to add adjustPan.

> **"adjustPan"**
>
> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically
> panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and
> users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less
> desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft
> keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

So according to the above, add the following to your activity manifest

Answer (score 0):

at the `AndroidManifest` file on activity that use Bottomappbar remove `android:windowSoftInputMode`